# How to Change google chart text and axis color based on themes

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, css, charts

[Theme 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGbl5.png)
[Theme 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nz3G.png)

Hi, I have statistics data of my project and I drew charts based on the data.

I have to apply graph text color and axis text color for multiple themes.

Initially I had two themes(Light & Dark).

I need White text for dark theme and Black text for Light Theme. For Reference I've added the image sources.

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: var options = {
                chart: {
                },
                legendTextStyle: { color: '#FFF' },
                titleTextStyle: { color: '#FFF' },
                hAxis: {
                    color: '#FFF',
                },
                bars: 'vertical',
                vAxis: { format: 'decimal' },
                height: 300,
                colors: ['#3cacd0','#1b9e77']
            };